# Android Version settings

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I want my Xamarin Android app to support API levels 16 and higher.  But I am confused by the fact that there are three different version settings in the properties pane of visual studio.

The names of the properties are

```
Compile using Android version
Minimum Android to target
Target Android version
```

Minimum I get.  It should be 16.  But what about the other two?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

### The simple answer

Let all three settings have the same value:

Set `Compile using Android version` to *the version that has all the features you need*.

Set `Mininum Android to target` to **Use Compile using SDK version**.

Set `Target Android version` to **Use Compile using SDK version**.

### The less simple answer

If you want to use newer features but still be backwards compatible:

Set `Compile using Android version` to *the version that has all the features you need*.

Set `Mininum Android to target` to *the lowest version you want to support*.

Set `Target Android version` to **Use Compile using SDK version**.

In your code you have to make sure the app works with the minium version as well:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Honeycomb)
{
    // Do modern stuff.
}
else
{
    // Do it the old-fashioned way.
}
```

Read more details here: http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/